# How to use dom-construct to insert an iframe with a query string and read the request in the controller?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dojo

I'm trying to send an array of a custom type back to an MVC controller using a query string in a get request. My model is the following:

```
public class SectionViewModel
{
    public string Building { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

My dojo looks method for posting back looks like the following:

```
xhr.get({
    url: '/Admin/Manage/CreateReport',
    content: { 'schedules': JSON.stringify([
        {
            Building: 'test',
            Number: 123
        },
        {
            Building: 'asdf',
            Number: 321
        }])
    },
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
    dataType: "json",
    load: function (data) { }
});
```

My controller is the following:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreateReport(List<SectionViewModel> schedules)
{
    return null;
}
```

The variable schedules in the controller method is an empty list and is non-null when debugging. I've tried a bunch of different combinations of forming the content but I am stuck. I do not know how to structure the content in such a way that my controller will accept it. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**SOLUTION:**

The get request was a requirement. I was using domContruct to inject an iframe with the source set to a query string. The controller method parses the get contents and generates a spreadsheet from the results. So the final code ended up looking like this:

**The iframe code:**

```
domConstruct.create("iframe", {
    src: '/Admin/Manage/Test?test=' + JSON.stringify(model),
    style: 'display: none;',
}, dojo.doc.body);
```

**The model code:**

```
public class SectionViewModel
{
    public string Building { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string Professor { get; set; }
    public List<User> Students { get; set; }
}
```

**The controller code:**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult Test(string test)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer jSerial = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var result = jSerial.Deserialize<List<SectionViewModel>>(test); 
    return null;
}
```

This feels sort of hackish but it gets the job done. I was stuck on this for hours. If this can be done without the use of JavascriptDeserializer please let me know!

Comment: Why get is requirement?

Answer (score 2):

content should look like following

```
content:  JSON.stringify([
        {
            Building: 'test',
            Number: 123
        },
        {
            Building: 'asdf',
            Number: 321
        }]),
```

and then change xhr.get to xhr.post
then add HttpPost to you action in Web.Api

Remember

**GET** - Requests data from a specified resource

```
/test/demo_form.asp?name1=value1&name2=value2
```

**POST** - Submits data to be processed to a specified resource

```
POST /test/demo_form.asp HTTP/1.1
Host: w3schools.com
name1=value1&name2=value2
```

[More info](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this once I get home. What do you mean by only using parameters in querystring for a get request? How would this query string be formed for the above controller action?

Comment: I am still unable to get my controller to recognize the content. Schedules is non null with a count of 0. It seems that if I manually create the query string with: ?schedules[0].Building=test&schedules[1].Number=123 it works. I'm not sure how to get this kind of string from dojo though. I looked into io-query but it did not supply the array index

Comment: I have posted a solution section with the updated javascript using domConstruct.create(..)